# AND $filter on object

Tags: angularjs, filter

I've an object with different properties and i was wondering how to filter them on several filter without creating a new custom filter , for exemple i've the "People" object containing a City and a Language, actually i can sort them only by there city or there language but not both with these line :

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>
      Search for user...
    </label>
    <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" class="demo-header-searchbox md-text" flex>
</md-input-container>

<md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchTerm ">
    {{user.city}} {{user.language}}
</md-option>
```

How to avoid creating new cutom filter please ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is you trying to do? Create filter by more then one object property without creatin custom filter one?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I would like to create a filter for exemple if I write "Paris English" it'll display every user that leave in Paris and Speak english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create `filter` by more then one object property you can use `filter` framework filter.

> **In HTML Template Binding** {{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}. Where `expression` can be `string`, `Object` or `function`.

According [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> **Object:** A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property name ($ by default) can be used (e.g. as in {$: "text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its nested object properties.

to create filter by `City` and a `Language` properties just use:

```
<md-option 
    ng-value="user"
    ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {City:searchTerm, Language: searchTerm }">

  {{user.city}} {{user.language}}
</md-option>
```

also you can use `function` parameter to solve your issue

> **function(value, index, array):** A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.
>
> The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

just write function that where filter value based on your search term

Comment: Thanks you for that answer, I just tried your solution with ``filter: {City:searchTerm, Language: searchTerm }`` but for exemple if I type "Paris" then that filter will return nothing because it search for a model with Paris as city (as expected) but with "Paris" as language so it wont return nothing...

Comment: @TotoNaBendo actually to completely match your requirements you need different `searchTerms` per properties, or you should write custom function as I mentioned. Which implement all you requirements and return for all record boolean value `isMatched` or not